# get reference of MainActivity in Application

Tags: android

I have `Application` class `VTS` and  `MainActivity`. I need to get reference of `MainActivity` in `Application` `VTS` class and call `MainActivity's` method `show(String t)`. How to get this reference to `aaa` variable?

```
<application
    android:name=".VTS"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>


public class VTS extends Application 
{
MainActivity aaa;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public void show(String t)
{
//...
}

}
```

Comment: [`Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks))

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I'm not sure why you'd want to invoke an activity's methods from the Application class, but in any case, you can set a weak reference to the activity inside the application class.

I haven't tested this, but this is one way that I think could work.  For simplicity, this assumes you're not dealing with concurrency issues.

```
public class VTS extends Application 
{
    static WeakReference<MainActivity> aaa;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static void setMainActivity( MainActivity activity ) {
        if ( aaa != null ) {
            aaa.clear() ;
        }

        if ( activity != null ) {
            aaa = new WeakReference< MainActivity >( activity );
        }
    }
    public MainActivity getMainActivity() {
        if ( aaa == null || aaa.get() == null ) {
            Log.e("VTS", "Main activity is null");
            throw new RunTimeException("Main activity is null") ;
        }
    }

    public void someMethodThatCallsMainActivity() {
        try {
            getMainActivity().show( "Hello world!" ) ;
        } catch ( Exception e ) { 
            e/printStackTracer() ;
        }
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        ...
        VTS.setMainActivity( this ) ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ...
        VTS.setMainActivity( null ) ;
    }

    public void show(String t)
    {
        //...
    }

}
```